# make accept attribute reads only css files

Tags: javascript, css

how to make `accept` attribute accepting `css` file type or `js` files ?

```
<input type="file" name="NAME" id="fileinput2" accept=".css" onchange="check()" />
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<input type="file" name="NAME" id="fileinput2" accept=".css,.js" />
```

But W3C recommends to specify both MIME-types and corresponding extensions in the accept attribute. So, the best approach would be:

```
<input type="file" name="NAME" id="fileinput2" accept=".css, .js, text/css, application/x-javascript" />
```

For complete Mime types Refer [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use comma separated value for `accept` attribute.

Like this:

```
<input type="file" name="NAME" id="fileinput2" accept=".css,.js" onchange="check()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate each extension by a comma

```
<input type="file" name="NAME" id="fileinput2" accept=".css, .js" onchange="check()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) the `accept` attribute accepts a comma separated list.